# Get value of ASP:TextBox when clicking an ASP:Button

Tags: html, asp.net, postback

I know this is a stupid question, and a simple question, but I feel like I'm going crazy as I can't get this working (even though I've done it a million times before).

I have a text box and a button in my ASP.NET page

```
                <asp:TextBox ID="commentTextBox" inputtype="text" runat="server" CssClass="uk-textarea"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="buttonComment" runat="server" CssClass="uk-button uk-button-text" text="Post Comment" OnClick="buttonComment_Click" />
```

These are a part of a larger set of HTML markup, that is wrapped in a:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
```

On button click, I do the following (get the value of the text box and post it to a database as a 'comment')

```
    protected void buttonComment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //string commentText = ((TextBox)FindControl("Comment")).Text;
            string strDate = Request.Form["commentTextBox"].ToString();

            Spark.Comment comment = new Spark.Comment
            {
                CommentByEmail = Context.User.Identity.Name.ToString(),
                CommentDate = DateTime.Now,
                SparkId = sparkId,
                CommentText = strDate,
            };

            using (var client = new AmazonLambdaClient(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2))
            {
                var request = new InvokeRequest
                {
                    FunctionName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["lambdaArnPrefix"] + "lambdaSparkCreateComment",
                    Payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(comment),
                    InvocationType = InvocationType.RequestResponse
                };

                var response = client.Invoke(request);
            }

            Response.Redirect($"SparkDetail?action=comment");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            sparkCardSingle.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

I've tried all these variations of getting the value:

```
string commentText = ((TextBox)FindControl("commentTextBox")).Text

string commentText = Request.Form["commentTextBox"].ToString();

string commentText  = CommentText.Text;
```

But no matter what, I get this error on post back

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at APISpark.SparkDetail.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\jmatson\Source\Repos\Production-Spark-Website\APISpark\SparkDetail.aspx.cs:line 136
```

I don't understand. I feel like I've done this code a billion times before and it works. I have no idea why it's not working now.

Comment: Error message is referring to Page_Load event line:136. you are checking button click event

Comment: Show your `Page_Load` method where the exception occurred. Since it throws NRE, check if the variable/field/property on line 136 already initialized and/or containing data.